# デプロイ先（heroku）でwagtail（DjangoCMS）マイグレートができない

Tags: django, heroku

以下のページを参考にwagtailを使って開発したウェブアプリケーションをデプロイしました。

[Deploying a Wagtail Site on Heroku](https://github.com/CodingForEverybody/wagtail-heroku-deployment/blob/master/README.md)

以前、別のアプリをデプロイした経験があるため、問題なくデプロイができました。（heroku-18に）

そこでマイグレートしようとしたのですが、自分がstartappで作成したアプリを含むいくつかのフォルダーはマイグレートされませんでした。ちなみに具体的なエラーメッセージはなく、ログも問題ないようです。

makemigrations,migrate実行後表示されるのは

```
 Your models in app(s): 'contents', 'flex', 'footer', 'forms', 'home', 'menu_header_wagtail', 'site_settings' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

です。指示通り、繰り返し行っても同じことが起きます。

**試したこと**
マイグレートと数回挑戦
デプロイしなおし
herokuのアプリを消して再度デプロイ
DB削除→マイグレート

本当にわかりません。どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

ローカルでマイグレートとし、プッシュすることで解決できました。